# VS2017 DesignInstance Intellisense not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

For some reason the intellisense in VS2017 is not showing the properties of my viewmodels, even though I used the `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:TestVm, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"` method.

Example of my class:

```
public class TestVm
{
    private int _test;

    public int Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; }
    }
}
```

Yet the property Test isn't showing up in my intellisense:
[image]

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: hope this help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720439/vs-2017-intellisense-not-working-c-sharp-and-xaml

Comment: I tried them out but none seemed to fix it